# How to exclude hidden data when exporting report to CSV on SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-csv, ssrs-2012

I have this report that has a parameter that users can select which view will appear when they run the report.

It has 3 options, **Cluster view**, **Country view** and **Raw data view**. Cluster view has a matrix and chart in one rectangle, Country view shows a matrix then Raw data view is a simple table.

I just hide the object when they are not included on the view. I put an expression on Hidden property.

So now, my problem is when I extract the report in csv. with Raw data view selected, the file includes the datasets for the two other views. How can I remove those so users can only see the data for raw data view?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have each view set up as a separate report. Instead of parameters, the first report would have links to the other reports. You can do this with a textbox action. When they choose to export it will only be able to export the dataset from the report they have chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV Renderer doesn't respect the hidden property.  I would say use [&RenderFormat.Name] as a dataset filter to exclude the data itself, but unfortunately you can't use that variable as a parameter or tablix filter.

You could create a CSV-export version of the report.  Then you could create a link on the main report which specifies the export mode with a link, using the format:  http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will give that a try.